WIX: Add an additional installer to setup and run it silent
I've added Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime installer to my WIX setup. No problem so far but I want it to be installed silently. Is it possible with Wix Toolset and if yes how?
<CustomAction Id="InstallMSWebview2" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" ExeCommand="[INSTALLFOLDER]MicrosoftEdgeWebView2RuntimeInstallerX86.exe" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" Return="ignore"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  ...
  <Custom Action="InstallMSWebview2" After="InstallFiles"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence> 


Answering my own question.
Solution is to add "/silent /install" as parameter to the installer. As like following:
<CustomAction Id="InstallMSWebview2" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" ExeCommand="[INSTALLFOLDER]MicrosoftEdgeWebView2RuntimeInstallerX86.exe /silent /install" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" Return="ignore"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence> 
  ...
  <Custom Action="InstallMSWebview2" After="InstallFiles"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence> 

